# How to update the state of a field programmatically using redux-form

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux-form

I currently have 2 inputs which look like this: 
[image]
I'm trying to update the end date input based on the first date input. Example if I input 08/15/2018 inside start date input I expect end date input to equal 08/15/2018.

My current code looks like this for end date input:

```
<Field
    component="input"
    format={(value, name) => {
       if (startDate.length && name === "start_date") {
          return startDate;
       }
       return value;
    }}
    name="end_date"
    onChange={onDateChange}
    type="date"
/>
```

- The variable `startDate` captures the input from start date input
- The current code is able to display the date under end date input, however, it is not updating the redux field - it remains undefined.

How can I display the data and also save it in redux form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import { getFormValues, change } from 'redux-form';
```

Fetch value of field first

```
const mapStateToProps = state => ({ 
    formValues: getFormValues('<formname>')(state) || {},
});
```

Access that field inside above object received. formValues.

You can use change to change value in store.

```
change(field:String, value:any) 

export const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({ 
setDate: value => dispatch(change('<formName>', value, null)),
});
```